# Database Schemas in Impala

Tags: database, hadoop, impala

I am from Oracle background and wanted to understand how DB schemas work (if they exist) in Hadoop world specifically in Impala. For e.g. Can we have tables with the same table_name in 2 different Impala Schema like we can have them in 2 schemas in Oracle DB. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, databases are logically separated in Hive & Impala